# Como extrair um dado de um array em php

Tags: php, array

Boa pessoal, bom esse meu pequeno script para postagens verifica se ja existe, se sim ele nao grava, se nao ele grava no bd. Quero colocar nele um sistema de curtida, entao eu criei uma tabela mas para eu indentificar a postagem e tal eu preciso do ID do post.. Até ai tudo certo.. Se vc olhar la no "print_r($idcheck);" ele me retorna um array com o id e o post, mas eu presiso extrair o id em forma de string, mas pela minha falta de conhecimento até ag não consegui resolver isso..

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 62
            [conteudo] => jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
        )
)
preciso só do id, mas quando eu coloco echo $idcheck["id"] ou idcheck[0] da erro..

```
        $status = 1;

        if( isset( $_POST['publicar'] ) ){

            date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
            $form['data']       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $form['conteudo']   = str_replace( '\r\n', "\n", DBEscape( trim( $_POST['conteudo'] ) ));
            $form['status']     = DBEscape( strip_tags( trim( $status ) ) );
            if( empty( $form['conteudo'] ) )
                echo'';
            else {

                $dbCheck = DBRead( 'posts', "WHERE conteudo = '". $form['conteudo'] ."'" );

                if( $dbCheck )
                    echo '<script>alert("Desculpe, mas já contaram esse segredo!");</script>';
                else {

                    if( DBCreate( 'posts', $form ) ){
                        $idcheck = DBRead( 'posts', "WHERE conteudo = '". $form['conteudo'] ."'", 'id, conteudo');  
                        var_dump($idcheck);
                        echo '<pre>';
                        print_r($idcheck);
                        echo '</pre>';
                        //echo '<script>document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "visible";</script>';
                        echo '<script>alert("Seu segredo foi postado com sucesso!");</script>';
                    }
                    else
                        echo '<script>alert("Desculpe, ocorreu um erro...");</script>';
                }
            }

        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
$id = (string)$idcheck[0]['id'];
```

Pelo que vi, essa variável $idcheck é um array multidimensional.
Também sugeri forçar o valor para string, para certificar de que a variável $id receberá o valor como string.

Comment: deu certoo!! valeu.. Eu tambem encontrei outra forma, fazer um foreach dentro de outro

Comment: Dá certo também fazer dois laços... mas se a variável é pequena dessa maneira e não contém muitos dados, acessar o valor diretamente pode ser melhor. De qualquer forma, boa sorte!

Comment: Valeu, ajudou muito!